# Code does not iterate correctly

Tags: python-2.7

I know there is many similar problems on this site, but unfortunately I was not able to fix my own with the existing answer.. I hope you don't mind to help me.
I have a code and am trying to append values to a list while iterating through the code. However, something goes wrong in the process and I end up with value 0.
I am not very good at debugging yet so I can't find the problem.
I made a simpler version of the code with less variables below:

```
    `import math
    from pylab import *
    import numpy as np

    #---------------------------INITIALIZATION-----------------------

    #initializing the parameters of the model
    Dt = 1
    time_step = 50

    #initializing the connection weights
    w1 = 1

    #initializing parameter values for the alogistic function

    steepness_SS_a=1

    speed_SS_a=1

    threshold_SS_a=1

    #--------------------THE FUNCTIONS---------------------------

    def initialize():
        global t, timesteps, WS_a, SS_a, new_WS_a, new_SS_a
        #initialize model states

        WS_a=1
        SS_a=0


        # initialize lists to update all states

        new_SS_a=np.array([SS_a])


        #initializing time list
        t=0.
        timesteps=[t]

    def observe():
        global t, timesteps, WS_a, SS_a, new_WS_a, new_SS_a



        np.append(SS_a, new_SS_a)


        timesteps.append(t)

    def update():
        global t, timesteps, WS_a, SS_a, new_WS_a, new_SS_a

        # for each state activation value, write how to update it in the form of new_WS(a)=function(WS(a))

        SS_a = SS_a + speed_SS_a * (((1/(1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a * (w1 *         WS_a - threshold_SS_a))))-(1/(1+math.exp(steepness_SS_a *threshold_SS_a))))*        (1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a*threshold_SS_a))-SS_a)

         # for each state activation value now move the state value to new value

        SS_a=new_SS_a 


        #updating the timestep
        t = t + Dt 

    #--------------------THE PROGRAM-----------------

    initialize()

    while t<30.:
        update()
        observe()

    #--------------------PLOTTING--------------------
    print SS_a
    plot(new_SS_a)

    show()`
```

Comment: and what result did you expect?

Comment: I am using a logistic function that incorporates the previous value of a state and other parameters in order to have it increase incrementally each timestep

Comment: mmm, try ploting `timesteps` instead

Comment: That generates a straight line between (0,0) and (30,30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot, show

def model():
    Dt = 1
    time_step = 50

    #initializing the connection weights
    w1 = 1

    #initializing parameter values for the alogistic function
    steepness_SS_a=1
    speed_SS_a=1
    threshold_SS_a=1

    #initialize model states
    WS_a=1
    SS_a=0
    # initialize lists to update all states
    new_SS_a=np.array([SS_a])
    #initializing time list
    t=0.0
    timesteps=[t]    

    while t<30.0:
        ## update()
        # for each state activation value, write how to update it in the form of new_WS(a)=function(WS(a))
        new = SS_a + speed_SS_a * (
                    (
                        (1/(1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a * (w1 * WS_a - threshold_SS_a))))
                        -
                        (1/(1+math.exp(steepness_SS_a *threshold_SS_a)))
                    )
                    *        
                    (1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a*threshold_SS_a))
                    -
                    SS_a
                )
        new_SS_a = np.append(new_SS_a,new)
        # for each state activation value now move the state value to new value
        SS_a=new 
        #updating the timestep
        t = t + Dt     

        ##observe()
        #np.append(SS_a, new_SS_a)
        timesteps.append(t)

    print( SS_a )
    print( new_SS_a )
    print( timesteps )
    plot(new_SS_a)
    show()        

model()
```

the mayor change is in `SS_a = SS_a + speed_SS_a *...` first I save that value like `new = SS_a + speed_SS_a *...` then I add that value to `new_SS_a` with `new_SS_a = np.append(new_SS_a,new)` (you need to catch the result of this, otherwise you lose it) and override the old one in `SS_a=new`

The other thing is that I put all together because the use of globals in this fashion is a bad practice, global should be used as constants and don't be modify, if you need to change it in base to a function result, then make that function return that value and then make the change to the global constant. Also `import *` is another bad practice because pollute your namespace with unneeded stuff and in some cases that extra stuff can override without your knowledge some other that you need, and is worse is you use multiple of those because make the debugging harder by hiding from were it come each stuff forcing you to make extra lookup to figuring which stuff belong to each library if you don't know or don't remember, so always use explicit imports

Comment: It works! You are the best :) It makes a lot more sense now and it is information that I can definitely use more often.

Comment: I don't know if you can see this c

Comment: huh? what happens?

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought I took that comment out.. I wanted to ask something else about this code but I did not know whether I was allowed to do that in this topic so I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162657/accessing-a-value-from-an-np-array-from-a-while-loop   Sorry!