# Accessing a value from an np.array from a while loop

Tags: python

### I have the following piece of code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from pylab import plot, show

    def model():
        Dt = 1
        time_step = 50

        #initializing the connection weights
        w1 = 1

        #initializing parameter values for the alogistic function
        steepness_SS_a=1
        speed_SS_a=1
        threshold_SS_a=1

        WS_a=1
        SS_a=0
        new_SS_a=np.array([SS_a])
        t=0.0
        timesteps=[t]    

        while t<30.0:

            new = SS_a + speed_SS_a * (
                    (
                        (1/(1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a * (w1 * WS_a - threshold_SS_a))))
                        -
                        (1/(1+math.exp(steepness_SS_a *threshold_SS_a)))
                    )
                    *        
                    (1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a*threshold_SS_a))
                    -
                    SS_a
                )
            new_SS_a = np.append(new_SS_a,new)

            SS_a=new 
            t = t + Dt     


            timesteps.append(t)

        print( timesteps )
        plot(new_SS_a)
        show()        

    model()
```

It is a computational model (I actually have more variables, this is a simplified version of the code), and during a certain period of time, the states of the model like SS_a have to update. Right now, the code works, but I want to make it more transparant, so you can extract a value of a certain state for a certain timestep.
I tried to do this with a for loop, and to give an index to each state for each timestep like this:

```
   for i in range (30)
        SS_a[i+1] = SS_a[i]+ speedfactor*(….. - SS_a(i))*Dt
```

, but this did  not work because I can't add those values to a list.
However, I wondered whether there is a possibility in the code I have now, with the while loop, to extract these values and make the model more declarative and transparant?

Now another option is to use the following format:

```
    import math
    from pylab import plot, show
    def model(Dt=1, time_step = 50, w1 = 1, steepness_SS_a=1, 
              speed_SS_a=1, threshold_SS_a=1, WS_a=1, SS_a=0, 
              t=0, t_final=30):
        result = [SS_a]
        timesteps =[]
        for ti in range(t,t_final+1,Dt):
            result.append(SS_a + speed_SS_a * (
                (
                    (1/(1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a * (w1 * WS_a -       threshold_SS_a))))
                -
                    (1/(1+math.exp(steepness_SS_a *threshold_SS_a)))
                )
                *        
                (1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a*threshold_SS_a))
                -
                SS_a
            )) #<- put here your complicate formula 
        timesteps.append(ti)

    print(result)
    print( timesteps )  
    plot(result)
    show()

model()`
```

However, the result is as follows:

```
    [0, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789, 0.3160602794142789]
```

But I am expecting the value to change. What can i do to improve this?

Comment: maybe you should use a list in the construction and if you need a numpy array make the conversion at the end

Comment: The problem is that the following: for i in range (30)
        SS_a[i+1] = SS_a[i]+ speedfactor*(….. - SS_a(i))*Dt does not work, because I get the error   'TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__''. Or am I placing the for-loop in the wrong location?

Comment: that is because you're using the list wrong,

Comment: oh, I see you make a edit, when I say "<- put here your complicate formula" I don't mean literally put the same thing there, you need to make the necessary adjust of course, that in this case is change `SS_a` for `result[-1]`

Comment: Yes I did that. But I think the latest version is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you want to put in a list a new value that depend in the previous value put there, you can do it like in this example

```
result=[0] #we put the initial value in the list
for _ in range(30): # the _ is to signal that we don use that value
    result.append( 10 + result[-1] ) # negative indices access the element in reverse order, -1 is the last, -2 is the previous to that etc
print(result)
```

with append we add a element to the end of the list

so in your code that is

```
...
def model():
    ...
    SS_a = [0]  
    for _ in range(30):
        SS_a.append( SS_a[-1]+ speedfactor*(... - SS_a[-1])*Dt )
    ...
    plot(SS_a)
    show()
```

you can even make your model more flexible by using arguments and default values, that way if you want to make some change just change how you call the model and not your code, for example like this

```
import math
#import numpy as np 
from pylab import plot, show
def model(Dt=1, time_step = 50, w1 = 1, steepness_SS_a=1, 
          speed_SS_a=1, threshold_SS_a=1, WS_a=1, SS_a=0, 
          t=0, t_final=30):
    result = [SS_a]
    timesteps =[]
    for ti in range(t,t_final+1,Dt):
        result.append( ... ) #<- put here your complicate formula 
        timesteps.append(ti)
    print( timesteps )  
    plot(result)
    show()
    #return result  

model()
```

with all those default values we preserve the original behavior, and if we want to do only a minor change like run that model until time 40 instead of 30 we simple call it as `model(t_final=40)`, you can also put a return of `result` so you can do some other manipulation later on, and we can also put a doct text to remember what each thing is in a easy way, like this

```
def model(Dt=1, time_step = 50, w1 = 1, steepness_SS_a=1, 
          speed_SS_a=1, threshold_SS_a=1, WS_a=1, SS_a=0, 
          t=0, t_final=30):
    """This is my model of ...
       where
       Dt: ...
       time_step: ... 
       w1: ...
       steepness_SS_a: ...
       speed_SS_a: ...
       threshold_SS_a: ...
       WS_a: ...
       SS_a: ...
       t: initial time
       t_final: final time
    """
    ...
```

and that we tell you a nice message that explain the model and how to used it is you call help on it `help(model)`

---

as you have several models, you can extract the commons part of each one in different pieces of code and make more general version of it so they can be used as lego block to build your different models, for example your original code can be broken like this

```
import math
#import numpy as np
from pylab import plot, show

def model_generator(fun, initial=0, t_ini=0, t_end=30, t_step=1 ):
    """Generator of all the values of the given function in the given
       time interval 

       fun: function of 2 arguments time and a previous value that 
            return a new value
       initial: initial value
       t_ini: initial time
       t_end: end time
       t_step: time interval"""
    yield initial
    new_value = initial
    for t in range(t_ini, t_end+1, t_step):
        new_value = fun(t, new_value)
        yield new_value

def model_plot(mod_gen):
    """plot a given model in the form of a iterable"""
    result = list( mod_gen )
    plot(result)
    show()         

def model_fun(t, SS_a, speed_SS_a=1, steepness_SS_a=1, w1=1, WS_a=1, threshold_SS_a=1  ):
    """function that represent my model of ..."""
    return SS_a + speed_SS_a * (
                (
                    (1/(1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a * (w1 * WS_a - threshold_SS_a))))
                    -
                    (1/(1+math.exp(steepness_SS_a *threshold_SS_a)))
                )
                *        
                (1+math.exp(-steepness_SS_a*threshold_SS_a))
                -
                SS_a
            )        

def model_1():
    """original model"""
    model_plot( model_generator(model_fun) )  

def model_2():
    """original model but with speed_SS_a=2"""
    fun = lambda t,SS_a: model_fun(t, SS_a, speed_SS_a=2)
    model_plot( model_generator(fun) )

def model_3():
    """random test model """
    fun = lambda t,p: t**2
    model_plot( model_generator(fun) )    


model_1()   
model_2()
model_3()
```

in this one that complicate formula is extracted in a independent function `model_fun` as it only need 1 obligatory/variable parameter to work (everything else is a constant), `model_generator` do the work of map time to the values of a function that is given to it as a parameter (because in python everything is a object, even a function, by the way this a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) function) and that function is required to receive 2 arguments time and the previous value (I include time because that make more sense to me, therefore model_fun also receive it but is ignored) and also handle the time stuff and finally `model_plot` that do what its name imply.

With all the pieces ready I can make as many models as I want and I don't have to repeat anything and the work is reduced to defining only the function, and I can use [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) functions to modify how I call a previous function like in `model_2` or define a new one like in `model_3`, or make a totally new one and as long I follow the rules set by `model_generator`, as they said, the sky is the limit (or something like that).

Comment: Wow thnx you helped me a lot.. :)

Comment: is my pleasure. Have you checked my last addition?

Comment: I did now, it is very good advice thnx. The problem is that i have more than 100 parameters to set for each simulation so I think I will lose the overview if I do it like that. However, i do want to try to make the model more flexible. Btw., I had to change al the math.exp to np.exp because I had an OverFlow error:Math Range  error. With np.exp it works, but I get an RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp. Does this matter?

Comment: well you don't have to set all 100+ parameters this way, only the more relevant or the ones that vary between model. You can also extract the similar parts into another function(s) and in each model call those functions, that way you avoid repetition of code. About the error, looks like you get overflow either way

Comment: I added another example, maybe that will help you to make a more general/flexible version of your work

Comment: Hi, I have two problems: When I implement the first example (result.append etc.) it seems to work, but if I use two variables, as follows:  `resultx=[0] resulty=[0]
for _ in range(30): 
    resultx.append( 10 + resultx[-1] )  resulty.append( 10 + resultx[-1] ) 
print(result)` Gives: `resultx = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300]
resulty = [0, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310]`

Comment: But I wanted the resulty to use the previous result x, otherwise the model does not work correctly.

Comment: Btw, is there another way to show my code more easily and be able to write more in one comment?

Comment: Because also when I implement your second example, with functions, and print the result, I get a list of identical values, although the value should be higher each timestep.

Comment: the comment section is limited and because the nature of python write multi-line code here will be a little weird, you can edit the post of your question with the new problem as it is related to my answer or make a new question.

Comment: Ok I'll make another question

Comment: about `resultx` and `resulty` what result did you expect? and my example with `model_fun` and etc produce the same plot as the original to me, well I leave the timesteps list out because the example don't really use it, but that is a easy fix if you need that list

Comment: I want result y to take the previous value from resultx, so it should be the same list as x in the end.

Comment: if that is the case, just make a copy of the x list, like `resulty=list(resultx)`

Comment: No, it has to acces the previous value from resultx. Because in the entire model, some states are influence by multiple states (e.g. Resultz is influences by resultx and resulty), but the new state of z has to be based on previous x and y..

Comment: in that case first extract the old value like for example `x,y=resultx[-1], resulty[-1]` produce the new values like for example `newx=x+10`, `newy=x+10` and then save those to its list `resultx.append(newx)`, `resulty.append(newy)`, or some other variation to the same effect.